# Cubase 10 Drum Editor Problem

Tags: midi, daw, cubase

[image: Cubase 10 Drum Editor]

I opened cubase 10 the other day and found that the descriptions of the drum set and notes for midi are missing from the left side of the editor where they should be. I cannot seem to find a way to bring them back, or am I missing something? I couldn't locate any answers on the cubase forum either. Can anyone please help?
Thank you.